# Pytorch 1.0: what does net.to(device) do in nn.DataParallel?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

The following code from the tutorial to [pytorch data paraleelism](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html) reads strange to me:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = Model(input_size, output_size)
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
  print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
  # dim = 0 [30, xxx] -> [10, ...], [10, ...], [10, ...] on 3 GPUs
  model = nn.DataParallel(model)

model.to(device)
```

According to my best knowledge, `mode.to(device)` copy the data to GPU.

> DataParallel splits your data automatically and sends job orders to multiple models on several GPUs. After each model finishes their job, DataParallel collects and merges the results before returning it to you.

If the `DataParallel` does the job of copying, what does the `to(device)` do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They add few lines in the [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html#create-model-and-dataparallel) to explain `nn.DataParallel`.

> DataParallel splits your data automatically, and send job orders to multiple models on different GPUs using the data. After each model finishes their job, DataParallel collects and merges the results for you.

The above quote can be understood that `nn.DataParallel` is just a wrapper class to inform `model.cuda()` should make a multiple copies to GPUs.

In my case, I don't have any GPU on my laptop. I still call `nn.DataParallel()` without any problem.

```py
import torch
import torchvision

model = torchvision.models.alexnet()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
# No error appears if I don't move the model to `cuda`
```

Comment: Hi, I think your original explanation is better, could you please leave that here?

Comment: Sure. I just paraphrased the quote - `nn.DataParallel` is just a wrapper class to inform `model.cuda()` should make a multiple copies to GPUs.

Comment: I think your statement is better than the quote. Besides, I quoted that as well but I don't think it helps me understand.

Comment: Thanks. I just added to the answer :D