# Replacement of var.to(device) in case of nn.DataParallel() in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, dataparallel

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828687/pytorch-1-0-what-does-net-todevice-do-in-nn-dataparallel) available but the answer is not relevant.

This code will transfer the model to multiple GPUs but how to transfer data on GPU's?

```
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
      print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
      # dim = 0 [30, xxx] -> [10, ...], [10, ...], [10, ...] on 3 GPUs
      model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0, 1])
```

My question is what is the replacement of

```
X_batch, y_batch = X_batch.to(device), y_batch.to(device)
```

What should be `device` equal to in the `DataParallel` case

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to transfer your data manually!

The [`nn.DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html) wrapper will do that for you since its purpose is to distribute the data equally on the different devices provided on initialization.

In the following snippet, I have a straightforward setup showing how a data-parallel wrapper initialized with 'cuda:0' transfers the provided CPU input to the desired device (*i.e.* 'cuda:0') and returns the output on the same device:

```
>>> model = nn.DataParallel(nn.Linear(10,10), device_ids=[0])

>>> model(torch.rand(5,10)).device
device(type='cuda', index=0)
```

Comment: in question, i am using 2 devices and my question is about training data but not about model. Model is working fine.

Comment: Yes, if you read my answer carefully you will see how `DataParallel` handles data transfer without having to transfer them manually to separate devices. I thought that 
was made quite clear in the answer I wrote above...